# How to get all logical disks associated only with exact hard drive using WMI?

Tags: c#, wmi, wmi-query

In example, I have an index of physical drive, and I want to get all logical drives on it, so I try this:

```
var searcher2 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format("ASSOCIATORS OF {{Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE{0}'}} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_LogicalDisk", index));
```

But it finds nothing.
Where did I go wrong?